# How to return/export only data showing on screen in custom post type view all screen

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta, export, csv

If I for example filter my custom post type by date and it only shows 2 records on screen, I only want to export those 2 records, but it is exporting a bunch of records out of my control ie: the wrong records.

How can I modify this to only export what is showing up on screen ie: the 2 records in this case?

```
add_action( 'init', 'func_export_some_records' );
function func_export_all_posts() {
    if(isset($_GET['export_some_records'])) {
        $arg = array(
                'post_type' => 'shirts',
                'fields' => 'ids'
            );


        global $post;
        $arr_post = get_posts($arg);
        if ($arr_post) {

            header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
            header("Content-Type: application/csv");
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="wp.csv"');
            header('Pragma: no-cache');
            header('Expires: 0');

            $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');

            fputcsv($file, array('COLUMN ONE', 'COLUMN TWO'));

            foreach ($arr_post as $post) {

                $color = get_post_meta( $post, 'user-color', true );
                $size = get_post_meta( $post, 'user-size', true );

                fputcsv($file, array($color, $size));
            }


            fclose($file);

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the button that triggers the download:

```
add_action( 'manage_posts_extra_tablenav', 'admin_post_list_top_export_button', 20, 1 );
function admin_post_list_top_export_button( $which ) {
    global $typenow;

    if ( 'shirts' === $typenow && 'top' === $which ) {
        ?>
        <input type="submit" name="export_some_records" id="export_some_records" class="button button-primary" value="Export Some Records" />
        <?php
    }
```

}

One way I thought of but not actually sure how to achieve is to get all the post ID's currently on screen and then in my $arg array use `'includes' => 'post id here'`

Comment: Read this  https://stackoverflow.com/a/28090348/3886203

Comment: @DanielGross, thanks for that. That doesn't really do what I want. I still isn't exporting the records on the screen. I only want to export what I can see basically. There are some details in the slug but not sure if I need to use those `Filter&paged=1&action2=-1`

Comment: What about getting all the post ID's and then using `'include' => 'all id's here'` in the $args array?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//edit.php?s&post_status=all&post_type=shirts&action=-1&m=0&slug=03-02-2020&filter_action=Filter&paged=1&action2=-1 
//$parse_uri = explode('wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
//require_once($parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php');
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: application/csv");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="wp.csv"');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: 0');

global $post;

//https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/
$post_status = isset($_REQUEST['post_status']) && $_REQUEST['post_status']=='all' ? 'any' : 'publish';
$date = explode('-',$_REQUEST['slug']);
$posts_per_page = $_REQUEST['action2'];
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

$arg = array(
    'post_type' => $_REQUEST['post_type'],
    'post_status' => $post_status,
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'date_query' => array(
        'column' => 'post_date',
        'year' => $date[2],
        'month' => $date[1],
        'day' => $date[0],
    )
);

$posts = new WP_Query($arg);

if($posts->have_posts()){

    $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    fputcsv($file, array('COLUMN ONE', 'COLUMN TWO'));


    while ( $posts->have_posts() ){
        $posts->the_post();

        $color = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'user-color', true );
        $size = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'user-size', true );

        fputcsv($file, array($color, $size));
    }

    fclose($file);

}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't work. I have updated my question with the button that triggers the download. That should probably help. Apologies for committing it initially.

Comment: There is no need to apologize! I didn't pay attention to the question. If it is to filter by date, I edited the code.  But there's something else in https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/

Comment: Still nothing. But, maybe it is the date format? Here is the actual slug. `edit.php?s&post_status=all&post_type=shirts&action=-1&m=0&slug=03-02-2020&filter_action=Filter&paged=1&action2=-1`

Comment: I think I get it. I'm going to write something

Comment: Ready. I edited it.

Comment: I had to add this back in to see my data `'fields' => 'ids'`, but it still shows the incorrect data, not what I have filtered.

Comment: I thinl I forgot... $arg['meta_query'] = array('relation' => 'AND');

Comment: Sadly still not working. Still dumping out wrong data :(

Comment: New Edition. And now?

Comment: Unfortunately still not. Is there not a way to get the current ID's on the page and use those instead of the date?

Comment: It's an idea. This way... 'post__in' => $post_ids . But I'm going to write something new here for you to filter by date.

Comment: Done. See there

Comment: Thank you, I am trying it but the site just dies. This site can't be reached.ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE

Comment: I still think it might be worth using the Id's instead but I don't know how to get all the ID's currently in the filter

Comment: About ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE, maybe, increase maximum execution time in php.ini

Comment: About the IDs, you want to list the items and then send the IDs by parameter in the url, right?

Comment: I think I need to go with the ID method, I think it will be more reliable than trying to use the date filter. Doing this works how I want but I have hardcoded the ID's in. It should get them dynamically         `$arg = array(
              'post_type' => 'shirts',
      'fields' => 'ids',
      'include' => array(1, 2, 3),
      'post_status' => 'any'
            );`

Comment: No, I don't think the ID's need to be in the URL. You should just be able to get them without having to get anything from the URL but I could be wrong. I don't see list of the ID's in the url when I have filtered by date.

Comment: Right. But, instead 'include' use 'post__in'

Comment: See "Display only the specific posts" at https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/

Comment: But include is working. I just need a way to dynamically insert the ID's instead of hardcoding them in. Do you know how I can list all the current ID's of the records being displayed on the page, that is what I need.

Comment: I am using `get_posts()`, not `WP_Query` so I think it's different https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/

Comment: Yes, you're right. get_posts accept 'include'

Comment: I am trying `'include' => $post_id's` but still not exporting what is in my filter.

Comment: Before I wrote something considering the WP_Query. I'm going to test it here with get_posts.

Comment: I've done something different now. See above!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105292/discussion-between-daniel-gross-and-user10980228).

Answer (score 0):

Create a file (csv.php) at the root of your template and to test, change the IDs.
Then run the code by accessing the URL:
//www.your_domain/wp-content/themes/your_template/csv.php

```
<?php
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: application/csv");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="wp.csv"');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
header('Expires: 0');

$parse_uri = explode('wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
require_once($parse_uri[0] . 'wp-load.php');

$color = '';
$size = '';

$post_ids = array('68251','68159');

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'shirts',
    'nopaging' => true,
    'post_status' => 'any',
    'include' => $post_ids,
);

$posts = get_posts($args);

if($posts){

    $file = fopen('php://output', 'w');

    fputcsv($file,array('COLUMN ONE','COLUMN TWO'));

    foreach ($posts as $post){

        $color = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'user-color', true );
        $size = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'user-size', true );

        fputcsv($file,array($color,$size));
    }

    fclose($file);

}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you Daniel. But I think I just figured it out. I get the date filter from the slug ie: `$_GET['slug']` and then in my $args array I used `'meta_key'` => `'addition_date'` and `'meta_value' => $_GET['slug']`. I didn't think of this before!

Comment: Good to know that your code worked this way :)

Comment: I don't suppose you know how I can make this export each row in a separate file instead of multiple rows in one file?

Comment: One moment. Let me see...

Comment: I've been thinking! I don't see how to do it. I can research something.  But in this way it may confuse the visitor. I suggest you print on the screen two download links.

Comment: For my use case I need individual files rather, now that I think about it. But perhaps this can be a new question..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3663156/3886203

Comment: I found an idea in javascript http://jsfiddle.net/diegolamonica/ssk8z9pa/